# Unable to case COM object of type

Tags: c#, comobject

I'm getting a strange error when I'm trying to do a `foreach` through shapes on a page using Word interop

My code is as follows

```
    foreach (word.Shapes p in pages[3].Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes )
    {
        p.SelectAll();
    }
```

The exception I get for some reason is this and I've no idea what I should do to fix this.

> {"Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shapes'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{0002099F-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))."}

Comment: Instead of doing `word.Shapes`, have your `foreach` variable as a `var`. That will work regardless, then see what type it actually is.

Comment: Have you tried actually casting `p`? Like this: `(Word.Shapes)p` ?

Comment: @KobyDouek: Explicitly specifying the type in the `foreach` loop will perform the cast for you so casting should not make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Shapes` is the collection type, but in order to iterate the shapes, you have to use `Shape` as type for each object.

Comment: Thanks don't know how I didn't see this :)